# Javascript Loop based on input

Tags: javascript

I have a case:
If The user input `3`, then the output should be `1 2 start`.
If the user input `5`, then the output should be `1 2 3 4 start`.
If the user input more than `9`, then the output should be `Error`.

I tried the following code, but no idea how can I add the last number into string

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
let text = "";
for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  if (i == 5) break;
  text += i + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any idea please?
Really appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap you for loop in a function. Then you can concat the numbers and append the word `start` on return.

```js
const input = 15;
console.log(countdown(input))

function countdown(input) {
  if (input > 9) {
    return 'Error!';
  }
  c = '';
  for (let i = 1; i < input; i++ ) {
    c += ' ' + i;
  }
  return c + ' start';
}
```

In your case

```js
    const input = 5;
    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = countdown(input);
    function countdown(input) {
      if (input > 9) {
        return 'Error!';
      }
      c = '';
      for (let i = 1; i < input; i++ ) {
        c += ' ' + i + '<br/>';
      }
      return c + ' start';
    }
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. This is great! But How I can handle if the input is more that `9`, then the output should be `Error`..?

Comment: @Haminteu or you mean a limiter? if input more then 9 the funtion returns  error?

Comment: Yes, limiter. Thats what I meant. So when the input is let say 10. Then the output is `ERROR`. Really appreciated. Cheers,

Comment: @Haminteu I update the my answer. You put only a if condition in the funtion.

Comment: @Haminteu And works??

Comment: Champion mate! Why does it look so easy to you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Stack11</title>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<input type="number" min="1" id="myInput" value="1">
<button onclick="getResult()">
    GetResult
</button>
<script>

  let text = "";

  function getResult(){
      document.getElementById("demo").innerText = "";
      let myInput = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
      myInput = parseInt(myInput);

      // From 1 to 9 not included 9
      if (myInput < 9 && myInput > 0){
          // You are excluding 1 from the input: 3 => 1, 2 : 5 => 1, 2, 3, 4
          for (let i=1; i < myInput; i++){
              text += i + "<br>";
          }
      }else{
          text = 'Output: The use input is wrong.';
      }

      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
  }


</script>


</body>
</html>
```